# TSlint rule export-name ignore all after dot

Tags: nestjs, tslint

I have a NestJS application and learning to use best practices with `tslint-microsoft-contrib`. All fine but I stuck. I have a file `user.controller.ts` that contains a class `UserController`. With this `tslint` thought, that my class name should be `User` (not what I want). Please tell me what rule I must add to fix my issue. The error is in `export-name` rule.